# Rails & Active Record query to find parent events without a child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

An Event has_many Votes and a Vote belongs_to a User. How can I get a user's event's that they personally have not voted on? This was my best shot:

```
Event.includes(:votes).where.not("votes.user_id = ?", current_user.id)
```

But I am getting the below error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "votes"

Answer (score 3):

You need to either use a hash within the final parenthesis or use `references` as per [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations).  Here's the resulting code:

```
Event.includes(:votes).where.not("votes.user_id = ?", current_user.id).references(:votes)
```

Comment: Hmmm... not sure why this isn't working, but it's returning 0 events.

Comment: Event.includes(:votes).where(:votes => {:user_id => current_user.id})   <== this query gets all the events a user has voted on. But the opposite returns 0 results

Comment: Looks like I'm only searching through events that have at least 1 vote

Comment: I had to adjust to Event.includes(:votes).where("votes.user_id != ? OR votes.user_id IS NULL", current_user.id).references(:votes) .  thanks for pointing in the right direction